# Curve fitting for a function in R using ggplot2

Tags: r

I have the following example:

```
seed(123)
x<-runif(100)
y<-runif(100)

f <- function(x) { return(4 * x * (1 - x)) }
```

I want to show a hypothetical dependency with the function `f` and the data points of `x` and `y` as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Can anyone help using ggplot2?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `stat_function()`

```
df <- data.frame(x= runif(100), y = runif(100))
f <- function(x) { return(4 * x * (1 - x)) }

ggplot(aes(x,y), data = df) + geom_point() +
stat_function(fun=f)
```